# How to use custom font in String.xml file

Tags: android

I have use following code in String.xml file.Now my question is here i had use font face as Aerial.So is there any way where i can use my custom font instead of using aerial here..suppose my custom font is aa.ttf...so how that can i use here.
My code is

```
<string name="strt_dialog_desc">To start monitoring press and hold the date on which the latest cycle started.<![CDATA[<font face=Aerial>]]>Click OptionMenu for help!<![CDATA[</font>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 3):

// place your font in assets folder

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aerial.ttf");

tv.setTypeface(face);
tv.setText(R.string.strt_dialog_desc);
```

Comment: I know that thing but my question is how to do it in string.xml file

Comment: That is not possible. Typefaces are set on the textviews

Answer (score 2):

//use SpannableString dynamically to change the font

```
Typeface tfaerial=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aerial.ttf");
Typeface tfTradeGothicLight=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TradeGothic-Light.OTF");

String strt_dialog_desc=this.getResources().getString(R.string.strt_dialog_desc);

int upto=strt_dialog_desc.indexOf(".");

        if (strt_dialog_desc!=null)
        {
            aboutAuthTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            aboutAuthTV.setLineSpacing(1.2f, 1.5f);
            aboutAuthTV.setTextSize(23);

            SpannableString SS = new SpannableString(strt_dialog_desc);
            SS. setSpan ( new StyleSpan(tfTradeGothicLight.getStyle()), 0, upto,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            SS. setSpan ( new StyleSpan(tfaerial.getStyle()), upto, strt_dialog_desc.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            yourtextView.setText(SS);
        }
```

// this for changing the color in this way changing the font is notworking

```
String str="<font size =\"20\"><B>Bold</B> <br/> Then Normal Text<br/>
                         <i>Then Italic</i> </font>" +
                       "<br/> <font color=\"green\" >this is simple sentence </font>" +
                       "<br/> <font face=\"verdana\" >this is simple sentence </font>"+
                       "<br/><br/><br/><br/><a>this is simple sentence</a>";
      Spanned strHtml= Html.fromHtml(str);

       TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
       tv.setText(strHtml);
```

Comment: What if i want to add a colour from colours.xml : different for dark & light mode ?
( In the strings.xml font example )

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do the same by using this [code](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076) this will change font at runtime.

MyApp.java

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
  }
}
```

TypefaceUtil.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {

    /**
     * Using reflection to override default typeface
     * NOTICE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN
     * @param context to work with assets
     * @param defaultFontNameToOverride for example "monospace"
     * @param customFontFileNameInAssets file name of the font from assets
     */
    public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
        try {
            final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

            final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
        }
    }
}
```

themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- you should set typeface which you want to override with TypefaceUtil -->
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This worked for me, however it will change only the  `TextView`s and not the `string`s names

Answer (score -1):

You can set font by the following attribute

```
android:typeFace=
```

Comment: You just check my code.So inside my code i want to put my custom font instead of aerial