# How to change color of a text using HTML tag in Android

Tags: android, html

I have a string which contain three words. I want to show the three words in same textview but in different line. For this I have used `<br>` tag. Now I want to show the last word in red color. I tried so many codes but nothing worked for me.
My code snippet is

```
viewHolder.cutomerinfo.setText(
    customerDetail[0]+Html.fromHtml("<br>")+
    customerDetail[1]+Html.fromHtml("<br>")+
    Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>")+
    customerDetail[2]+Html.fromHtml("</font>"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like that:
code:

```
String toshowstring = customerDetail[0]+customerDetail[1]+
                      "<font color='red'>"+customerDetail[2]+"</font>";
viewHolder.cutomerinfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(toshowstring));
```

That's all you want.
^-^

Comment: @swati I did not answer (@enjoy-writing did), I just edited the post so you don't have to side-scroll to see all of the code. Good to hear it worked though! :)

Answer (score 0):

//only one Html.fromHtml() method is enough

```
   viewHolder.cutomerinfo.setText(
    customerDetail[0]+Html.fromHtml("<br>"+customerDetail[1]+
                                    "<br><font color='#ff0000'>"+
                                    customerDetail[2]+"</font>"));
```

[for Ref:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152727/1012284)

Comment: you can use \n for new line also.