# String size and font change in string.xml file

Tags: android, text-files

In my android application, i have to write a string into a file. Before that I want to format the string to make the font bold and have a new text size. So I modify the `string.xml` by

```
 "<string name="file_title" ><b>#title*</b></string>",
```

for bold the text and wrote to text file. But it is not showing as bold in the file.

1. Is that right method i used to implement the string bold?
2. Also i want to know how to change the text size of a string direct
   from string.xml

how to add that boldness in file... i tried

```
  "<string name="note"><![CDATA[<b>title</b>]]></string>"
```

in java code get your string

```
  yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.note)));
```

by using texview it"s coming bold , exaclty i want to write to file, using the below code

```
 "bufferWritter.write(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.note))));"
```

but i can"t see the boldness in my print.txt file...

Thanks & Regards
Anoop

Comment: How to use custom font in String.xml file http://stackoverflow.com/a/8152727/1012284

Answer (score 2):

You Should try to use dimens.xml for dimension values

then reference it @dimen/yourDimensionName

[Refer this link for](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Or other way is using HTML from java code

I tried this is working.

In your string.xml file try this

```
<string name="test"><![CDATA[<b>test</b>]]></string>
```

In your java code settext this string value from string resource like this

```
 textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test)));
```

Its working fine....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
in string.xml write like this

    <string name="note"><![CDATA[<b>title</b>]]></string>

in java code get your string
     yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.note)));
```

Comment: how to add that boldness in file... i tried  bufferWritter.write(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.note))));

Comment: @AnoopNarayan you are writing in bufferWritter if this text is directly set to your textview then this will in bold letter

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way. Just change its size from xml directly. use.

```
android:text="Date"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="xdp"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you should have your xml resource as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="file_title"><b>title*</b>!</string>
</resources>
```

And then use:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.file_title);
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
```

In order to change the text or other parameters, you can add a `<span></span>` with specific css style around your text.

For more information please check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Hope this helps!